# Is there a way to get a constraints-applied UIView frame in ViewDidLoad()?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, constraints, viewdidload

I need to know the exact position of an UIView frame created by a storyboard.

The problem is I get a non-constraints-applied frame in ViewDidLoad().

This drives me crazy all the time.

Because of this problem, I oftentimes abandon the whole idea of designing with storyboard.

I'd like to know if there's an elegant way to solve this initialization issue.

I've already tried awakeFromNib().

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is too soon. Try using `viewWillAppear:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **viewDidLoad** is called the constraints are not applied on the view.The constraints are applied on the **viewDidLayoutSubviews**. But With my work I found that **viewDidLayoutSubviews** worked fine in the ios8 but not always for iOS7 backwards.
   So my suggestion is that if your app is ios8 onwards use **viewDidLayoutSubviews** and if not what I'd suggest to hide the view in viewDidLoad and unhide it in viewWillAppear, only after the constraints have been applied. It gets you a small extra delay when loading the screen but the constraints change gets transparent to the user.It is very good from user point of view.

Answer (score 0):

When `viewDidLoad` is called constraints are not yet applied. If you want to retrieve the position of a view with constraints applied you have to wait for `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to gets called.
Note that this method will get called anytime the view has to change the positions of its subviews such as when you rotate the device.